# Finding color in detected outline opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

Greetings to all computer vision developers!
I need your hint - a vector that would lead me to the solution of my problem.

**The task itself:**
there is a code (see below) that finds moving objects using the background subtraction method. I need to find the color in these outlines, which will be set by the lower and upper boundaries of the HSV color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygYW5.jpg)

What do I mean by color search?

https://pysource.com/2019/02/15/detecting-colors-hsv-color-space-opencv-with-python/

**Code:**

```
        import cv2 as cv

        cap = cv.VideoCapture ('videos / 1.mp4')
        fgbg = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG ()

        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read ()
            if frame is None:
                break
            fgmask = fgbg.apply (frame)
            cv.imshow ('FG MASK Frame', fgmask)

            keyboard = cv.waitKey (30)
            if keyboard == 'q' or keyboard == 27:
               break
        cap.release ()
        cv.destroyAllWindows ()
```

**Question:**
How do I find the color inside this outline?

Comment: low = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)`code`
high = np.array([0, 0, 20], dtype=np.uint8)`code`

Answer (score 0):

```py
hsv_mask = cv2.inRange(frame, low, high)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, fgmask, mask=hsv_mask)
```

Comment: output = cv.bitwise_and(frame, fgmask, mask=hsv_mask)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-rwld3ghi\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:234: error: (-209:Sizes of inp
ut arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op a
rray' in function 'cv::binary_op'


                    gives an error message.